# where can I find php_memcached.dll php extension?

Tags: php, memcached

Spent a lot of time and I cant find a built version anywhere. please help.

Note: please don't turn me to php_memcache.dll. I have this one. I'm looking for php_memcached.dll.

Comment: Actually, php_memcached.dll is not exist for Window now. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693195/does-memcached-dll-exist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try below links :

[php_memcache-2.2.6-5.3-vc9-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_memcache-2.2.6-5.3-vc9-x86.zip)

[php_memtrack-0.1.0-5.3.0-nts-vc6-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_memtrack-0.1.0-5.3.0-nts-vc6-x86.zip)

[php_memcache-2.2.6-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_memcache-2.2.6-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip)

get more [click here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/)

Comment: Not memcache, He asked for *memcached*

Comment: the above links are not working and he asked for memcachedDDDDD

Answer (score -4):

Look like you are using windows environment (example: xampp)

so you will get it **your drive:\xampp\php\ext**

if you want to activate just un-comment from your php.ini file

Comment: This dll is not available with xampp