# Does memcached.dll exist?

Tags: php, windows, memcached

Does the memcached (not memcache) extension exist for Windows? I have looked through old answers and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the php extension "memcache" to use memcached with php on windows here http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Memcached is the server daemon and you can get it for windows here http://splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/

The php extension also called memcached requires libmemcached which doesn't seem well supported on windows which is probably why that extension doesn't exist for windows.

Comment: I thought I made it clear I am looking for memcached not memcache.

Comment: php_memcache.dll is the php extension to use memcached on windows. see my edit for more

Comment: @MarkBaker Yep, I noticed that and added it on my edit, the naming sure gets confusing there, since the memcached extension isn't a daemon itself, doesn't it? Thanks!

Comment: I guess your answer will be helpful to someone searching. And I suppose the answer to my question is "it doesn't exist." I need to append and memcache doesn't allow it.

Comment: I know your pain, I work primarily on windows, have you tried talking directly to memcached (the server) using a memcached cli wrapper (hacky I know) or read the value append and set it back (which has issues of course). If it's production those options shouldn't be used, but if it's development use they might help. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, so what I did was grab the value and then do an array merge on it and the new array. Works for now and will be using linux as the production server so once everything is good I'll just need to change a few things.

Comment: is php_memcached.dll available now?

Answer (score 10):

It does not exist and is very unlikely to exist any time soon. The main problem is not the extension itself but the libmemcached library. This library is barely portable to anything but a linux system, so windows support won't happen anytime soon (using Visual C).

Comment: Did anything change since you wrote this?