# Can we implement memcache without php_memcached.dll in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to implement memcache into my Zendframework 2 application.

For that, **is it possible to implement only with Zend framework 2 library** without php_memcache.dll and php_memcached.dll?

If not, How can I install php_memcached.dll. I have searched with google for php_memcached.dll they have given some daemon, kindly help me how to proceed with that daemon.

I have referred this links:

[Does memcached.dll exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693195/does-memcached-dll-exist)

http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/libmemcacheddll-32-bit-and-64-bit-php-extensions

Thanks.

Comment: So you'r running your php server on windows, You can't implement with only "zend framework 2 library" (i think), you need to implement that in the php parser, Do you know what PHP version you are in ? and if it is thread safe , non-thread safe, vc++, and so on.. do a phpinfo(); and get back at me

Comment: ya, It is thread safe and I am using PHP 5.4.7

Answer (score 0):

It isn't only possible to implement with Zend framewotk you can use it stand-alone with PHP

Read this for more enlightment (memcache vs memcached):

[When should I use Memcache instead of Memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442411/when-should-i-use-memcache-instead-of-memcached)

Now choose from memcache or memcached libs, Personally I would go to memcached, but since you are on windows I think your only choice is memcache.

**So download this zip:**

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/php_memcache-3.0.8-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip

**Unzip it, put php_memcache.dll in your extensions dir**, if you are using XAMPP the path would be something like C:\xampp\php\extensions\

**Edit your php.ini**

and include a line

```
extensions = php_memcache.dll
```

Restart the Apache, and boom you have memcache installed.

See this documentation on how to use memcache

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php