# How to use MemcacheD instead of Memcache on PHP and Windows Xampp?

Tags: php, caching, xampp, memcached, amazon-elasticache

Sorry but, I've searched this question and I found a lot of old answers.
Now, I can use memcacheD instead of memcache on windows?

http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-install-memcached-on-windows-machine

I installed php_memcache.dll extension and memcached.exe server service, but this is memcache! (without "D"). in fact if I use

```
new Memcache;
```

it works fine, instead if I use:

```
new Memcached;
```

or

```
new MemcacheD;
```

doesn't work.

I would like to implement memcacheD (with "D" !!!) because I will use it on amazon Elasticache together Zend Framework Cache/Session and it works with memcacheD. Now I'm working in Xampp (windows) ambient. How to work with memcacheD in windows? I need another libraries?

Thanks a lot, I'm fighting for using this -.-

I'm using Win7 (64bit).

My DDL file is available here (php 5.6 - 5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x86):

http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.8/windows

My memcached server version is 1.4.4 32bit version, available here

http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/10/15/Memcached-for-Windows&page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the two. `memcached` is the [Memcache daemon program](http://memcached.org/) (the `d` stands for daemon). This has to be running for you to use Memcache. This is NOT what you use inside PHP. You launch this inside Windows like you would any other program.

The Memcache PECL library is how you can connect to your running daemon. You use `new Memcache` inside PHP to create an object that connects to the daemon and then interacts with it.

Comment: ah, ok.
So, I would like to use Memcached class (PECL memcached extension), but in windows enviroment it isn't possible. :/

http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this myself, and it seems that the only solution is to compile the DLL yourself from source, because there are no official Windows binaries for the PHP memcached extension available. This is a related question: [Does memcached.dll exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693195/does-memcached-dll-exist)